# What reason is there to believe that 1st C Jews thought that being the Son of God = God?

Tags: nature-of-god, terminology, judaism, messiah, jewish-culture

One poster ask me the above question. Does anyone have a scriptural answer? I have one and will post it soon.

Comment: I am a little miffed at this question. The Jews did not believe Jesus was even the Messiah (that is why their leadership crucified him!). Why would you look to them as an authority on the Trinity doctrine? (What denomination is the person who gave you this question btw? This seems like a question from a denomination that doesnt understand the issues relating to this)

Comment: I was going to downvote this question, however, i have decided that in light of the context in which it is being asked...ie the person asking it doesnt understand the reality of Jesus crucifiction (the jews didnt believe he was the messiah), i have given it a thumbs up so that can be cleared up. It is only in more recent times that we have Messianic Jews who do believe Jesus was the messiah. Traditional Jews do not believe this (that is my understanding at least)

Comment: @Adam The person that ask the question I believe to be a unitarian. I think it's a valid question that needs to be addressed. Let me put the question another way. "So Adam, since Jesus is the Son of God on what basis do you trinitarians come to the conclusion that He is actually God? How is claiming to be the Son of God equal to Him being God? The question is not interested in what the Jews think today. How would you answer the question?

Comment: @Adam, I think you're misreading the question.  It doesn't say that Jews thought Jesus was the Son of God.  My understanding of it is as a question of whether Jews would interpret a claim of being the Son of God as equivalent to a claim of being God.

Comment: The answer is simple, you know, God is childless and not begotten. The question is why don't you believe it? If you cannot believe in the little things, how can you believe the big things?

Comment: @RayButterworth eh? The question says "what reason is there to believe 1st Century Jews thought/believeed that Jesus was God". The answer is that there is no possibility that they did believe this! Gentiles yes, but not Jews. Messianic Jews are a modern denomination...traditional Judaism doesnt believe he was the Messiah or God. I dont think arguing a couple of small groups believe in Him is relevant to the question as the question does not specify that...it appears to be asking generically.

Comment: @Adam, the question doesn't even mention Jesus.  And it certainly doesn't say "*Jesus was God*".  It says "*being the Son of God = God*". And this question has nothing at all to do with Messianic Jews.  Are we reading different questions, or what?

Comment: @RayButterworth are you now attempting to put forward the view that you do not believe that Jesus is the Son of God? The question has everything to do with Messianic Jews because "traditional Jews"  did not believe Jesus was the Son of God or the Messiah (which are biblical synonymous descriptors of the Christ, plainly made public by Pilot himself ). For centuries after the death of Christ, the leadership of the Jewish faith and therefore representative of the movement itself still waited for the fulfillment of the prophecy in Isaiah 9:6.  I think you are throwing red herrings Ray

Comment: @Adam, I am thoroughly confused by what you are claiming.  What I *am* saying is that *you* are adding the red herring.  The question nowhere mentions Jesus, but you keep misquoting it as if it did. The question is so detached from Christianity that it could easily be asked on Judaism.SE without offending anyone: *Does Judaism equate a claim of being the son of God with a claim of being God?*  Everything else you are talking about has been added by you.

Comment: @RayButterworth i think it may be difficult to adequately resolve that issue...the model that the Jews had to go by was Abram and Isaac. If one was to ask a Jew if Isaac was Abram (since Isaac was Abrams son), what might one think he would have said? Biblically the idea of God becoming his own son required the life of Jesus to not only explain, but to illustrate in the flesh! Since the Jews did not believe Jesus was either the Messiah or God, how can one expect them to answer the question?

Comment: @RayButterworth the nearest possible reference i can think of that may have been used by Jews in answering this question is the fabulous trinitarian gem Isaiah 9:6 6 "For unto us a child is born, unto us a son is given, and the government will be upon His shoulders. And He will be called Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God, Everlasting Father, Prince of Peace." If Jews believed Isiaiah 9:6, then they were clearly trinitarian!

Comment: @Adam, (Binitarian, not Trinitarian; there is no mention of a third person.)
But what you quoted was written by translators with a Christian bias.
Jewish translations render it as *… He has been named “The Mighty God is planning grace; The Eternal Father, a peaceable ruler”* — [Isaiah 9:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.9.5?lang=bi). (Note the different verse numbering.)
There is a Wikipedia article about this specific verse: [Pele-joez-el-gibbor-abi-ad-sar-shalom - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pele-joez-el-gibbor-abi-ad-sar-shalom).

Comment: @Adam asked "*Since the Jews did not believe Jesus was either the Messiah or God, how can one expect them to answer the question?*".  That is irrelevant to this question, which doesn't even mention Jesus or Messiah. If the question had instead said "*first century **BC***", before Jesus was even born, it would be the same question and deserve the same correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

My answer! The Jews have what is called "idioms." One of those idioms is called the "son of" idiom and can be found both in the Old Testament and New Testament.

For example in the OT you have "Sons of prophets." (1 Kings 20:35; 2 Kings 2:3, refer to men belonging to a prophetic band. "Prophethood" (that which distinguishes "prophets" from "non-prophets") is the very nature that unities the "sons of the prophets" with their metaphorical fathers, "the prophets."

The same holds true for the following examples. "Sons of the goldsmiths at Nehemiah 3:31. Sons of the troop (2 Chronicles 25:13) are men of the army. Sons of affliction (Proverbs 31:5) are afflicted ones. I think you get the idea.

In the NT, "Son of peace (Luke 10:6 refers to a peaceful person. Who was the Son of perdition?" (John 17:12, 2 Thessalonians 2:3) is the lost one, This is applied to Judas and the antichrist. One more, "Sons of thunder" was the appellative applied by Jesus to James and John at Mark 3:17 because it signified something outstanding about their character.

What about Jesus Christ who identified Himself on numerous occasions as "the Son of Man" and as "the Son of God." The idiom DOES intend the meaning of a shared nature between ANY father, and his son and thus between "THE Father and THE Son."

The "Son of God" title is entirely consistent with trinitarian doctrine which states explicitly that the Son is of the same NATURE of the Father. Christ really IS the "son" of God and therefore, BY DEFINITION shares the distinctive nature of his father just as ALL sons bear the distinctive nature of their fathers.

That Jesus is ALSO the "Son of Man" (obviously in the metaphorical sense, given the fact that his actual father was NOT any man) is also consistent with the doctrine of the trinity which claims that Christ was indeed truly a man.

There was a reason why the Apostle John ends his gospel account by stating his authorial intent at John 20:30-31. "Many other signs therefore Jesus also performed in the presence of the disciples, which are not written in this book; vs31, but these have been written that you may believe that Jesus is (1) Christ/Messiah, (2) the Son of God; and that believing you may have life in His name."

If you read the context of the following verses you will notice a pattern or trend in what the Jews conclude by Jesus' words. John 5:18, John 10:30, John 19:7 and the trial record at Matthew 26:57-65. It boils down to, "Are you the Christ/Messiah, and are you the Son of God?"

This is the question the high priest Caiaphas said to Jesus at Matthew 26:63. "And the high priest said to Him, "I adjure You by the living God, that You tell us whether (1) You are the Christ/Messiah, (2) the Son of God." Caiaphas puts Jesus under oath to swear as to His true identity. Jesus answers at Luke 22:70 by saying, "Yes, I am." (NASB)

Most of the information regarding Jewish "idioms" is taken from the following site. http://faculty.gordon.edu/hu/bi/ted_hildebrandt/OTeSources/23a-Prophets/Text/Articles/Bess-SonOfGod-GTJ.pdf

The article was written in 1965 and I only had some written notes of it from many, many years ago. I decided to look it up and I found the complete article. He also deals with the terms "Firstborn" and the term "Only Begotten."

Comment: Great answer Mr Bond +1 from me. Slight correction was needed, its Luke 22:70 (not 26:70) and i have also edited text...statement from Jesus is "you say that I am". Only minor changes and do not adversely affect the answer.

Comment: @Adam  NASB says “yes I am”

Comment: +1 for spelling this out, thanks for this. A couple of major problems with this analysis. 1. The Gospels tell us what the title 'the Son of God' means, Luke 1:31-35. It means that Jesus was conceived by the power of the Holy Spirit, not that Jesus is God. 2. The title 'the Son of God' in this context comes from Psalm 2, and was used as a co-referent with 'His anointed one' (= 'the Messiah') because these concepts (as well as 'King') are combined there. It was simply a way of marking out the person referred to in Psalm 2. ...

Comment: This is why these terms are routinely conjoined (8 times in the NT - was Nathanael, a devout monotheistic Jew, up and claiming Jesus was God at the beginning of John? Sounds implausible to me.).

Comment: @OneGodtheFather said "*The Gospels tell us …*".  Yes, but that is irrelevant to this question. First century Jews (e.g those that wanted to stone Jesus for blasphemy) hadn't read the Gospels.  The question isn't about what Christians thought, but about what Jews thought.

Comment: @RayButterworth Absolutely, the NT revelation clarifies the term which was in use among Jews at the time. The received use is the second part of my comment.  But the first part is largely a response to "Christ really IS the "son" of God and therefore, BY DEFINITION shares the distinctive nature of his father just as ALL sons bear the distinctive nature of their fathers." Look, Jews such as Caiaphas could have *believed this* (I don't think he did), but if so he misunderstood the title.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather And what proof do you have Caiaphas misunderstood the title? The Jews did not misunderstand what Jesus claimed. John 5:18, Jews claim Jesus was making Himself equal with God. John 8:5, Jesus claims to have existed before Abraham was born. John 10:30, Jesus claims to be equal in nature with His Father. Why else do the Jews accuse Him of blasphemy at vs33? John 19:7, Jews say He made Himself out the Son of God. Matthew 26:65 Caiaphas accuses Him of blasphemy. Now think, if the Jews misunderstood Jesus at His trial, why did they bring up the Law of blasphemy at Leviticus 24:16?

Comment: @Mr.Bond Jesus (supposedly) blasphemed in his trial for falsely claiming to be the Messiah (= the Son of God). Caiaphas pairs the two titles as synonyms (Matthew 26:63, Mark 14:61). Caiaphas correctly understood the title was a claim to (in his opinion, false) Messiahship. This was profaning God. But the Jews were confused about what Jesus was saying throughout John (Jesus said they misunderstood him (and were liars), and corrected their claims). You're mischaracterizing John 10:30, though - it's about ...

Comment: ...co-inherence, which Jesus clarifies in his response (10:38), just as the disciples and Jesus co-inhere (John 14:20).

Comment: @OneGodtheFather No one that I know of has ever been accused of blasphemy, let alone killed for claiming to be the Messiah. People have been claiming to be the Messiah from Jesus' time even to today. The Jews were expecting the Messiah but when Jesus swore that He was the Christ and the Son of God the Jews did not believe Him. Despite John 20:30-31 and God His Father giving His Son credibility, Luke 9:35 Of course they misunderstood Him on some things but that is not an excuse. His disciples misunderstood as well but in the end they believed Jesus was who He said He was. Read Acts and beyond.

Comment: @Kris the interlinear says "Ὑμεῖς λέγετε ὅτι ἐγώ εἰμι (You say that i am)  Indeed even your own JW interlinear says Ὑμεῖς (you) λέγετε (are saying ) ὅτι (that) ἐγώIεἰμι (I am). Do you not read your own watchtower interlinear?

Comment: @Adam "You say that I am" = "I am". Pulpit commentary on Luke 22:70, for ex., "This form of reply is not used in Greek, but is frequent in rabbinic. By such an answer the one interrogated accepts as his own affirmation the question put to him in its entirety."